# GSheets JSON String Splitter, with Dynamic Column Selection

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have the below script that I am using to split out a JSON string.
Currently it has a unique ID in Col A, and the Data in Col B.
I want to be able to have the data in any column, provided the column is called DATA.
I want the script to look for column titled data and keep all columns left of that in the out put tab.
I have tried a few things but none of them are working.
I have created a sample workbook here to show what I'm after [Splitter Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BMiVuAgDbibLw6yUG3IZ9iw4MZTaVVegkw_k3ItQ4mU/edit#gid=586997970)

Any help here would be amazing!

```
function JSON_SPLITTER() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var outputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current Output");

  // 0. 
  var response = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('JSON String Heading', 'Enter Column Heading for the JSON String in Row 1 Exactly as it appears', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL)
    var JSONcolumnname = response.getResponseText()

  // 1. Retrieve values from the input sheet.
  var [head, ...additionalinfo] = inputsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Check "DATA" column.
  var dataIdx = head.indexOf(JSONcolumnname);
  if (dataIdx == -1) throw new Error("No DATA column.");

  // 3. Retrieve all keys from JSON data of the "DATA" column.
  var headers = [... new Set(additionalinfo.flatMap(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : Object.keys(obj);
  }))];

  // 4. Create values of JSON data.
  var objValues = additionalinfo.map(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : headers.map(h => obj[h] || "");
  });

  // 5. Create output values.
  additionalinfo.forEach((r, i) => r.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...objValues[i]));
  head.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...headers)
  var res = [head, ...additionalinfo];

  // 6. Put the values to the output sheet.
  outputsheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: By guessing your goal from your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. At that time, can you provide your expected input and output situations? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `Currently it has a unique ID in Col A, and the Data in Col B. I want to be able to have the data in any column, provided the column is called DATA. I want the script to look for column titled data and keep all columns left of that in the out put tab.`, for example, when your "Sample Data 1" sheet is used, you want to achieve the following situation.

  - **From:** This is the header row of the input sheet.

    ```
      Contract Oid,Name,Age,DATA
    ```
  - **To:** This is the header row of the output sheet. In your situation, it is required to search `DATA` column for each input sheet.

    ```
      Contract Oid,Name,Age,{keys parsed from JSON data of "DATA"}
    ```

When I saw your script, it seems that "DATA" column is not searched. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function JSON_SPLITTER2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sample Data 1");
  var outputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current Output");

  // 1. Retrieve values from the input sheet.
  var [head, ...additionalinfo] = inputsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Check "DATA" column.
  var dataIdx = head.indexOf("DATA");
  if (dataIdx == -1) throw new Error("No DATA column.");

  // 3. Retrieve all keys from JSON data of the "DATA" column.
  var headers = [... new Set(additionalinfo.flatMap(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : [];
  }))];

  // 4. Create values of JSON data.
  var objValues = additionalinfo.map(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : Array(headers.length).fill("");
  });

  // 5. Create output values.
  additionalinfo.forEach((r, i) => r.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...objValues[i]));
  head.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...headers)
  var res = [head, ...additionalinfo];

  // 6. Put the values to the output sheet.
  outputsheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

- In this script, when "DATA" sheet is not found, an error occurs. If you want to finish instead of the error, please modify `if (dataIdx == -1) throw new Error("No DATA column.");` to `if (dataIdx == -1) return;`

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

### Added:

From your reply, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function JSON_SPLITTER3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var inputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sample Data 1");
  var outputsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current Output");

  // 1. Retrieve values from the input sheet.
  var [head, ...additionalinfo] = inputsheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // 2. Check "DATA" column.
  var dataIdx = head.indexOf("DATA");
  if (dataIdx == -1) throw new Error("No DATA column.");

  // 3. Retrieve all keys from JSON data of the "DATA" column.
  var headers = [... new Set(additionalinfo.flatMap(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : Object.keys(obj);
  }))];

  // 4. Create values of JSON data.
  var objValues = additionalinfo.map(r => {
    var obj = JSON.parse(r[dataIdx]);
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : headers.map(h => obj[h] || "");
  });

  // 5. Create output values.
  additionalinfo.forEach((r, i) => r.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...objValues[i]));
  head.splice(dataIdx, 1, ...headers)
  var res = [head, ...additionalinfo];

  // 6. Put the values to the output sheet.
  outputsheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  
This works except now it is not pulling in the data from the last row.
Where the conditional logic was before to make it not dependent on finding the additional info tag first. Could you help add that part back in please?

Comment: @Simon Hardham Thank you for replying. From your showing script, I had thought that you wanted to retrieve the values from `additionalInfo`. And I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `This works except now it is not pulling in the data from the last row. Where the conditional logic was before to make it not dependent on finding the additional info tag first. Could you help add that part back in please?`, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide your expected input and output situations? By this, I would like to modify the script.

Comment: @Simon Hardham Unfortunately, I cannot see your input and output situations, is the following modification your expected result? From `return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : [];` to `return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? Object.keys(obj.additionalInfo) : Object.keys(obj);`. And also, From `return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : Array(headers.length).fill("");` to `return obj.hasOwnProperty("additionalInfo") ? headers.map(h => obj.additionalInfo[h] || "") : headers.map(h => obj[h] || "");`.

Comment: Basically I need the script to work for either with additional info or without EG both of these:

{   "additionalInfo": {     "UANNumber": "123", l   } }
AND:
"{
  ""isComplianceUploaded"": true,
  ""isOpsOnboardingComplete"": true
}"

Currently the second one returns a blank result.

Comment: Currently the last row is returning blank, when it should return:
  isComplianceUploaded: true,
  isOpsOnboardingComplete"": true

Comment: That's what this part of the script was doing:  

// prepare the additionalInfo  data to be parsed for later
  var data = additionalinfo.slice(1).map(row => {
    // collect all keys in an array
    if (JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo) {
      keys.push(Object.keys(JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo));
      return JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo;
    }
    else {
      keys.push(Object.keys(JSON.parse(row[1])));
      return JSON.parse(row[1]);
    }
  });

Comment: @Simon Hardham Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand your reply. Can you include your expected result in your provided sample Spreadsheet using your sample input sheet? By this, I would like to try to understand your actual goal. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Yes Tanaike, no need to apologise, thank you for helping.
I have two tabs, Current Output and Expected Output 1.
You'll notice in the  Expected Output 1 the last row has data, in current output it does not.
I need the last row to also populate, despite it not having "Additional Info" in the string

Comment: This part of the script with the "Else" statement does it  
// prepare the additionalInfo  data to be parsed for later
  var data = additionalinfo.slice(1).map(row => {
    // collect all keys in an array
    if (JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo) {
      keys.push(Object.keys(JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo));
      return JSON.parse(row[1]).additionalInfo;
    }
    else {
      keys.push(Object.keys(JSON.parse(row[1])));
      return JSON.parse(row[1]);
    }
  });

Comment: @Simon Hardham Thank you for replying. I saw your updated Spreadsheet. Using it, I added one more sample script? Could you please confirm it? if that wat not useful, I apologize, again.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you Tanaike, I appreciate your work!

Comment: Hi Tanaike, the script is not working now for my data set, I have post the data in the GSheet JSON Splitter Example, could you please help?

Comment: One of the employees in our DB is in a funny format:
"{
  ""additionalInfo"": null,
  ""isComplianceUploaded"": true,
  ""isOpsOnboardingComplete"": true,
  ""originalSignDate"": ""2021-07-16T02:53:59.180Z""
}"
So this is where the issue is being caused
Can you help here?

Comment: @Simon Hardham About your new question, I would like to support you. So can you post it as a new question? Because your new question is different from your 1st question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I'll post a new question sure thing!